# How do i kill mobs in a radius of 2 blocks from my armorstand using a commandblock 1.16.2

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am making a map where the an armor stand represents the player, so the armorstand keeps getting teleported to the player. I also want to make enemies and if an enemy (zombie) gets in a radius of 2 blocks of the armorstand it dies.

I already had an command, but that killed all zombies 2 blocks from the command block, not the armor stand.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You say you had "a command" beforehand. What was it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The armor stand can only teleport to the player when there is only one player. If not, then the armor stand cannot be automatically moved, because there are multiple possible targets that the armor stand can teleport to. However, to kill all the mobs within 2 blocks is simple.

Have a repeating command block, set to always active, with command:

```
/execute at @e[type=armor_stand] run kill @e[type=!armorstand,type=!player, distance=0..2]
```

The `@e[type=armorstand]` executes this **only** on armor stands, and not on other entities like pigs or players. The `[type=!armorstand,type=!player, distance=0..2]` part kills all entities that are not players or armor stands that are less than 2 blocks from the armor stand. This prevents the armor stand from disappearing or the player being killed due to being inside the "force field."

I hope this helps.

Comment: /execute @e is not valid in the commandblock, its all red

Comment: @Timo203 I have made changes to the answer. Does this work?

Comment: The hole text is still red, I am in 1.16.2

Comment: I think I got it

Comment: OMG You're such a legend TY SO MUCH

Comment: Remember that you can always upvote or accept my answer if you think it helps you.

Comment: I do have one more question, I also want to make it when a zombie gets in a radius of one block near the armorstand the armorstand gets tpd back to the beginning

Comment: @Timo203 If you have another question, please post it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). Include a link to this question if it helps provide context.